# Need help speeding up numpy code that finds number of `coincidences' between two NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am looking for some help speeding up some code that I have written in Numpy. Here is the code:

```
def TimeChunks(timevalues, num):
    avg = len(timevalues) / float(num)
    out = []
    last = 0.0

    while last < len(timevalues):
        out.append(timevalues[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg

    return out
### chunk i can be called by out[i] ###

NumChunks = 100000
t1chunks = TimeChunks(t1, NumChunks)
t2chunks = TimeChunks(t2, NumChunks)

NumofBins = 2000

CoincAllChunks = 0
for i in range(NumChunks):
    CoincOneChunk = 0
    Hist1, something1 = np.histogram(t1chunks[i], NumofBins)
    Hist2, something2 = np.histogram(t2chunks[i], NumofBins)

    Mask1 = (Hist1>0)
    Mask2 = (Hist2>0)
    MaskCoinc = Mask1*Mask2
    CoincOneChunk = np.sum(MaskCoinc)
    CoincAllChunks = CoincAllChunks + CoincOneChunk
```

Is there anything that can be done to improve this to make it more efficient for large arrays?

To explain the point of the code in a nutshell, the purpose of the code is simply to find the average "coincidences" between two NumPy arrays, representing time values of two channels (divided by some normalisation constant). This "coincidence" occurs when there is at least one time value in each of the two channels in a certain time interval.

For example:

```
t1 = [.4, .7, 1.1]
t2 = [0.8, .9, 1.5]
```

There is a coincidence in the window [0,1] and one coincidence in the interval [1, 2].

I want to find the average number of these "coincidences" when I break down my time array into a number of equally distributed bins. So for example if:

```
t1 = [.4, .7, 1.1, 2.1, 3, 3.3]
t2 = [0.8, .9, 1.5, 2.2, 3.1, 4]
```

And I want 4 bins, the intervals I'll consider are ([0,1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4]). Therefore the total coincidences will be 4 (because there is a coincidence in each bin), and therefore the average coincidences will be 4.

This code is an attempt to do this for large time arrays for very small bin sizes, and as a result, to make it work I had to break down my time arrays into smaller chunks, and then for-loop through each of these chunks.

I've tried making this as vectorized as I can, but it still is very slow...
Any ideas what can be done to speed it up further?

Any suggestions/hints will be appreciated. Thanks!.

Comment: Are you sure the `np.histogram` is correct. It is very surprising to compare directly histograms of different ranges. The default range is not `[0,1]` but `[a.min(), a.max()[`. Is the range missing? Moreover, your code put every value of the example array in an independent chunk which is very suspicious (eg. something like `[..., [0.4], ..., [0.7], ..., [1.1], ..., [2.1], [3], ..., [3.3], ...]`). This means you compute histograms with 0 value >99.9% of the time and 1 value at most in the remaining case. Actually, `np.histogram` is useless in the example use-case.

Comment: You are right. I am now doing it the right way of choosing the range to be [a, b[ where a is smaller of the two minima from the 2 arrays and b is larger of the two maxima from the arrays. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is 17X faster and more correct using a custom made `numba_histogram` function that beats the generic `np.histogram`. Note that you are computing and comparing histograms of two different series separately, which is not accurate for your purpose. So, in my `numba_histogram` function I use the same bin edges to compute the histograms of both series simultaneously.

We can still optimize it even further if you provide more precise details about the algorithm. Namely, if you provide specific details about the parameters and the criteria on which you decide that two intervals coincide.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def numba_histogram(a, b, n):
    hista, histb = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.intp), np.zeros(n, dtype=np.intp)
    a_min, a_max = min(a[0], b[0]), max(a[-1], b[-1])
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        bin = n * (x - a_min) / (a_max - a_min)
        if x == a_max:
            hista[n - 1] += 1
        elif bin >= 0 and bin < n:
            hista[int(bin)] += 1        
        bin = n * (y - a_min) / (a_max - a_min)
        if y == a_max:
            histb[n - 1] += 1
        elif bin >= 0 and bin < n:
            histb[int(bin)] += 1
    return np.sum( (hista > 0) * (histb > 0) )

@njit 
def calc_coincidence(t1, t2):
    NumofBins = 2000
    NumChunks = 100000
    avg = len(t1) / NumChunks
    CoincAllChunks = 0
    last = 0.0
    while last < len(t1):
        t1chunks = t1[int(last):int(last + avg)]
        t2chunks = t2[int(last):int(last + avg)]
        CoincAllChunks += numba_histogram(t1chunks, t2chunks, NumofBins)
        last += avg 
    return CoincAllChunks
```

Test with `10**8` arrays:

```
t1 = np.arange(10**8) + np.random.rand(10**8)
t2 = np.arange(10**8) + np.random.rand(10**8)
CoincAllChunks = calc_coincidence(t1, t2)
print( CoincAllChunks )
 # 34793890    Time: 24.96140170097351 sec.  (Original)
 # 34734897    Time: 1.499996423721313 sec.  (Optimized)
```

Comment: Note that if `a_min` and `a_max` are equal then there is a division by zero in the Numba code (I think this was the case on the example code)

Comment: @Jerome Yes, indeed I ran into that problem. I edited it to ignore the cases when there is only one element in that chunk which happens more often than I would like.

Comment: @AboAmmar the way I decide on the parameters is: Since these are time values associated with an event, I need to consider number of events & the time interval over which they are spread. For instance I have time values that are spread over 1 second interval & I want to make chunks that are ~ (1-10)micro seconds bcos I am not interested in values that are separated by more than 10microseconds.  So the number of chunks will be ~ 100k. Bin size is chosen to make sure that there is not more than 1 event in each bin. I typically want bin sizes to be (10-100)ns, So I am looking to have ~1000bins.