# Need help speeding up a Python code that counts coincidences with a shift

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vectorization, numba

I previously posted a question about trying to make a code more efficient. The purpose of the code is simply to find the average "coincidences" between two NumPy arrays, representing time values of two channels. This "coincidence" occurs when there is at least one time value in each of the two channels in a certain time interval.
I break up the long arrays into ~(10k-100k) chunks. These chunks are then binned and I calculate coincidences between analogous bins. ie. (bin #n,chunk1 of array1) and (bin #n,chunk1 of array2).
Here is the link to the question:
[Need help speeding up numpy code that finds number of `coincidences' between two NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72850849/need-help-speeding-up-numpy-code-that-finds-number-of-coincidences-between-two/72854392#72854392)

Following the suggestions of @AboAmmar & @Jerome Richard: I changed the code with significant improvement in the speed.
Now, I have to add an additional step to also calculate shifted coincidences i.e between bin #n & bin #(n+shift) of the two chunks respectively and then do this for different values of shift. The code is faster than before but still too slow for the amount of the data that needs to be analyzed.

Here's how I did it:

```
@njit
def numba_histogram(a, b, n):
    hista, histb = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.intp), np.zeros(n, dtype=np.intp)
    a_min, a_max = min(a[0], b[0]), max(a[-1], b[-1])
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        bin = n * (x - a_min) / (a_max - a_min)
        if x == a_max:
            hista[n - 1] += 1
        elif bin >= 0 and bin < n:
            hista[int(bin)] += 1        
        bin = n * (y - a_min) / (a_max - a_min)
        if y == a_max:
            histb[n - 1] += 1
        elif bin >= 0 and bin < n:
            histb[int(bin)] += 1
    return hista, histb

@njit 
def calc_coincidence(t1,t2, NumChunks, NumofBins, td):
    CoincAllChunks = 0
    last = 0.0
    avg = len(t1) / NumChunks
    
    while last < len(t1):
        t1chunks = t1[int(last):int(last + avg)]
        t2chunks = t2[int(last):int(last + avg)]
        if (len(t1chunks)<=1) or (len(t2chunks)<=1):
            last += avg
            
        else:
            Hist1, Hist2 = numba_histogram(t1chunks,t2chunks,NumofBins)
            Hist2 = Hist2[td:]
            appendthis = np.zeros(td)
            Hist2 = np.append(Hist2, appendthis)

            CoincOneChunk = np.sum( (Hist1 > 0) * (Hist2 > 0) )
            CoincAllChunks += CoincOneChunk  
            last += avg 
        
    return CoincAllChunks

    ##### NumChunks,BinSize,Num of Delays ########   
NumChunks = 10
HowManyUnitsofns = 100
BinSize = HowManyUnitsofns*10**(-9)
NumberofDelays= 10

    ###################################################

NumberofFiles = 10
CoinAllDelaysAllFiles = np.zeros(NumberofDelays, dtype=np.int64)
ListofCoinforDiffDelays = []
for n in range(NumberofFiles):
    specificfile = 'file{}.h5'.format(n)
    t1, t2, DataTime = ReadFile(specificfile)
    
    #################### Normalization ################
    ChunkSize = (DataTime)/(NumChunks)
    NumofBins = int(ChunkSize/BinSize)
    Singles1 = len(t1)
    Singles2 = len(t2)
    Normalization = (Singles1*Singles2*BinSize)/DataTime
    ####################################################
    
    CoinAllDelaysOneFile = []
    for i in range(NumberofDelays):  
        CoinOneDelay = 0
        NormCoinOneDelay = (calc_coincidence(t1,t2, NumChunks, NumofBins,i))/Normalization
        CoinAllDelaysOneFile = np.append(CoinAllDelaysOneFile, NormCoinOneDelay)
        
    CoinAllDelaysAllFiles = np.vstack((CoinAllDelaysAllFiles, CoinAllDelaysOneFile))

for k in range(NumberofDelays):
    coineachdelay = np.sum(CoinAllDelaysAllFiles[:,k])
    ListofCoinforDiffDelays = np.append(ListofCoinforDiffDelays, coineachdelay)
    NormListofCoinforDiffDelays = ListofCoinforDiffDelays/(NumberofFiles)
    
print(NormListofCoinforDiffDelays)
tau = HowManyUnitsofns*np.arange(NumberofDelays)
plt.scatter(tau,NormListofCoinforDiffDelays)
plt.ylim(0,2)
```

What can I do to make this faster? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit**: I am basically looking for seeing how the number of coincidences vary with the shift value. So I calculate the number of coincidences for each shift and plot that vs shift value.
**Data to work with** :
https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/8168796/To%20upload%20on%20StackOverflow.zip

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to explain *in this post* exactly what needs to happen - show a small example of input, and the exact desired corresponding output. Also, if you actually do use this code at the moment, why is it commented out?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I was troubleshooting something so commented out this part. I edited my post to make it clear what I am trying to do and I also posted the whole code I wrote. In addition I also put up a link to some files to work with. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve your problems, but what might help, is parallelizing `numba_histogram`. I would suggest something like this:

```
@njit
slice_hist(x, n, hmin, hmax):
    hist = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.intp),
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        bin = n * (x - hmin) / (hmax - hmin)
        if x == hmax:
            hist[n - 1] += 1
        elif bin >= 0 and bin < n:
            hist[int(bin)] += 1        
    return hist

@njit(parallel=True)
numba_histogram(a, b, n):
    hista, histb = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.intp), np.zeros(n, dtype=np.intp)
    ntc = numba.config.NUM_THREADS
    a_slices, b_slices = np.split(a, ntc), np.split(b, ntc)
    hist_min, hist_max = min(a[0], b[0]), max(a[-1], b[-1])
    for i in numba.prange(ntc):
        hista+=slice_hist(a_sclices[i], n, hist_min, hist_max)
        histb+=slice_hist(b_sclices[i], n, hist_min, hist_max)
    return hista, histb
```

Depending on your machine and the chunk sizes limiting the number of utilized threads numba.config.NUM_THREADS might actually result in better performance. You can probably optimize it further by limiting the scope of the histogram in `slice_hist`, though I am not quite sure on that.